# c++ exporting and using dll function

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I can't quite figure out where there is a mistake. I am creating a DLL and then using it in a C++ console program (Windows 7, VS2008). But I get `LNK2019 unresolved external symbol` when trying to use the DLL functions.

First the export:

```
#ifndef __MyFuncWin32Header_h
#define __MyFuncWin32Header_h

#ifdef MyFuncLib_EXPORTS
#  define MyFuncLib_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
# else
#  define MyFuncLib_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
# endif  

#endif
```

This is one header file I then use in:

```
#ifndef __cfd_MyFuncLibInterface_h__
#define __cfd_MyFuncLibInterface_h__

#include "MyFuncWin32Header.h"

#include ... //some other imports here

class  MyFuncLib_EXPORT MyFuncLibInterface {

public:

MyFuncLibInterface();
~MyFuncLibInterface();

void myFunc(std::string param);

};

#endif
```

Then there is the dllimport in the console program, which has the DLL included in the Linker->General->Additional Library Directories:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>


__declspec( dllimport ) void myFunc(std::string param);


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::string inputPar = "bla";
    myFunc(inputPar); //this line produces the linker error
}
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong here; it must be something really simple and fundamental.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're exporting a class member function `void MyFuncLibInterface::myFunc(std::string param);` but trying to import a free function `void myFunc(std::string param);`

Make sure you `#define MyFuncLib_EXPORTS` in the DLL project. Make sure you `#include "MyFuncLibInterface.h"` in the console app *without* defining `MyFuncLib_EXPORTS`.

The DLL project will see:

```
class  __declspec(dllexport) MyFuncLibInterface {
...
}:
```

And the console project will see:

```
class  __declspec(dllimport) MyFuncLibInterface {
...
}:
```

This allows your console project to use the class from the dll.

EDIT: In response to comment

```
#ifndef FooH
#define FooH

#ifdef BUILDING_THE_DLL
#define EXPORTED __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORTED __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class EXPORTED Foo {
public:
  void bar();
};


#endif
```

In the project which actually implements `Foo::bar()` `BUILDING_THE_DLL` must be defined. In the project which tries to *use* `Foo`, `BUILDING_THE_DLL` should *not* be defined. *Both* projects must `#include "Foo.h"`, but only the DLL project should contain `"Foo.cpp"`

When you then build the DLL, the class Foo and all its members are marked as "exported from this DLL". When you build any other project, the class Foo and all its members are marked as "imported from a DLL"

Comment: Nice answer; essentially what I noticed.  Also, the function is not declared as static so you need an instance of the class to call the function.

Comment: I dont quite get the answear. Am i supposed to strip the Interface.h of the #imports and defines and include it with the console project? Can you be a little bit more specific.

Comment: @inf.ig.sh: If you want to use the class from the console project you have to include the .h in the console project. The console project needs to see the class declared as *dllimport* so that it'll look for the actual implementation in a DLL.

Comment: great answer. i just have one follow up question. could u explain more on #define MyFuncLib_EXPORTS? do u mean all required is putting this line of code in the dll and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the class not a function. After that, you can call the class member.

```
class  __declspec( dllimport ) MyFuncLibInterface {

public:

MyFuncLibInterface();
~MyFuncLibInterface();

void myFunc(std::string param);

};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
std::string inputPar = "bla";
MyFuncLibInterface intf;
intf.myFunc(inputPar); //this line produces the linker error
}
```